# loop decreased numbers in uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, loops, uitableview

I would like to loop my numbers into the uitableviewcell and printing all the values from the highest number to the lowest and printing them in each cell. I posted the full code. See the `cell.text` output. This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class tableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!


    var arr = [Int]()
    var cell:tableCell!
    var Payment: float_t! = 59600
    var years1: float_t! = //15 * 12 = 180
    var monthlyPayment: float_t! = 471
    var interest: float_t! = 5%
    var principal: float_t! = 222
    var interstate: float_t! = 249
    var initil: float_t!
    var data = Array<float_t>()
    var data2: NSMutableArray = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let c = Int(years1)
        arr += 0...c

        tableCalculation()


            let nib = UINib(nibName: "table", bundle: nil)
            tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")



    }

    func tableCalculation() {

        let years = Int(years1)
        initil = TPayment - 0

        for i in 0..<years {


                initil = initil - principil

                interest = initil * interestrate



                principil = monthlyPayment - interest

                print("Month : \(monthlyPayment),   principil: \(principil),interest: \(interest), initi: \(initil)")
                self.data2 = [initil]


        }

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arr.count
    }



    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell     {

        cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! tableCell
        cell.lbl1.text = "\(arr[indexPath.row])"

        cell.lbl2.text =  currencyFormatter(monthlyPayment)
        cell.lbl3.text = currencyFormatter(interest)
        cell.lbl4.text = currencyFormatter(principil)
        cell.lbl5.text = "\(self.data2[indexPath.row % data2.count])"

        return cell

    }

    // 4
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("Row \(indexPath.row) selected")
    }

    // 5
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 70
    }

    func currencyFormatter(Price: float_t) ->String {

        let currencyFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        currencyFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
        currencyFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
        // localize to your grouping and decimal separator
        let numberOfPlaces: float_t = 1.0
        let multiplier: float_t = pow(10.0, numberOfPlaces)
        let num = Price
        let rounded = round(num * multiplier) / multiplier
        let priceString = currencyFormatter.stringFromNumber(rounded)

        return priceString!
    }    
}
```

This code always gives me the last number of the loop for all values, I would like to change it to write from the first value to the last one in every cell.

Comment: You can't do it that way. The table view calls `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as it sees fit in the order it chooses, based on which rows are visible on the screen. You could store your calculations in an array, and display the contents in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: What's the point of that `if` statement? `initial` will always be equal to itself.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to SO. Neither your question nor your code make any sense.

It looks to me like you have no idea how to use table views.

You need to set up a data model (usually an array) that holds the data for your table view. Then when your cellForRowAtIndexPath method gets called, you look at the row (or row and section) in the request, fetch the data for that row (or row & section for a sectioned table view) and use that data to configure a cell which you return.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {        
    cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! tableCell        
    cell.lbl5.text = "\(initial - indexPath.row*225)" //subtracts each consecutive row by a higher multiple of 225.       
    return cell        
}
```

You need to understand that `cellForRow:atIndexPath` is a UITableView datasource method that's called by the UIKit framework. It gets called when the tableview is loaded, based on the number of sections (specified by another datasource method), and the number of rows in each section (also specified by yet another datasource method).

Comment: `initial - indexPath.row` is not at all what the OP wants in each cell.

Comment: His question states "printing all the values from the highest number to the lowest" - isn't that what this does?

Comment: Look at the code posted by the OP. I think each row would start with the initial balance and then decrement by the monthly payment. The OP isn't too clear but it certainly isn't meant do decrement each row by 1 as shown in your answer.

Comment: Okay it's not clear what he wants to achieve with the for-loop. Maybe it's a table to start with a sum and display the payments reduced by some monthly amount. The best I can guess is `initial - indexPath.row*225`.

Comment: what I want to do is calculate the amount by subtract a monthly payment for loan, tried to store the loop data in an array but shows me the last loop number

Answer (score 0):

Here's how table views work, like Duncan said you need to know.

```
/*We need to subclass UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate 
  so we gain access to tableView methods. Don't forget to link your 
  tableView in the storyboard to the delegate and datasource!*/

class controller: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    //1: Model. All the data you're gonna use for your table view
    var data = Array<String>()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        //1: Populate model with some data when the view loads.
        self.data = ["Oranges", "Apples", "Bananas", "Grapes"]
    }

    //2: Number of rows in table view. This determines how many times #3 is called (below).
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //We want the table view to have all the items in variable `data`. So, we need to have as many cells as the number of items in `data`
        return data.count
    }


    //3: This is called for each cell. It lets you customise each cell how you want. 
    //For us, we'll make the text inside the cell the current item in the `data` array
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //Get the cell from the tableView. Use the identifier you've specified in the storyboard.
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        //Set the text as the current item in `data`
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
        //Use this cell we've just created for the current row
        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: var data = Array<float_t>()


then add   "self.data = [initial] "  in the loop


cell.lbl5.text = "\(data[indexPath.row])"


this method gets me error "fatal error: Array index out of range"